# I installed CentOS to VM but it doesn't work

Tags: centos, virtual-machine

I installed CentOs to VirtualBox. However, after installation finishes, i reboot the system but i get black screen again installation.There is no CentOS start command/button. All are about installation again. How can i fix this situation ?
[image: screen]

Comment: Do you have text based command prompt?

Comment: No, i have nothing. When press reboot everything will turn to beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You have installation media (CD/USB drive) before HDD in boot order. Just remove/unmount ISO and let VM to boot from HDD.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it ? I am a new for this issues.